# A black screen is just flashing for a while

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my Windows phone 8 application i have a search page which has a TextBox for user's to enter search keywords. The search will invoke when entering the "Enter" key of the default SIP keyboard.The search result is showing in another page. To hide the keyboard before navigating to result page, I changed the focus of TextBox control using this.Focus() method. But even after this a black screen is just flashing for a while. Is there any way to completely hide the SIP keyboard before the search method and the navigation. Please help me.

Comment: I had the same problem. Do you have ApplicationBar in your page?

Comment: yes i have application bar in that page

Answer (score 4):

This is a rendering problem, one way to fix this is to change the the opacity ot the your `applicationbar`

```
<shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" Opacity="0.99">
```

When i had the same problem, i thought I needed to fix this WITHOUT changing the app bar. So  i went through the whole page and what seems to happen is that i had a lot of controls being built inside my panorama, but  it was not a direct child of the layout root grid, so that was causing the problem.

Let me know how it goes (:

Comment: still the issue is not fixed.But it occus rarely after hiding the appbar

Comment: After I read @Aneesh question and your answer I remembered that 4th & Mayor hides and shows the applicationBar every page transition. Maybe it is related.

Comment: The issue is fixed when the code for navigation is put in the UI thread.